# optimizing the query into one

Tags: php, mysql

can anybody help me to reduce this code.

```
$dat=  mysql_query
("SELECT wid,count(*) as count 
  FROM uptime 
  WHERE time_stamp>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
  AND  status<>200 GROUP BY wid ORDER BY  time_stamp ASC"
);

while($ans= mysql_fetch_assoc($dat))
{
   $count_array[]=$ans;
}

foreach ($count_array as $value) 
{
   if($value['count']==2)
   {
      $id=$value['wid'];
      $add=  mysql_query("SELECT email FROM website WHERE webid='".$id."'");
      $result=  mysql_fetch_assoc($add);
      <--etc etc to send email-->
    }
}
```

I need to reduce the code please help me.if the two queries can be combined without losing the meaning will also be helpful for me.

Comment: Start with removing empty lines. It will almost reduce this code twice.

Comment: "I want" --- is there some technical requirement or you just "want" it without any particular reason?

Comment: PS: there are not just 2 queries in total. The second one will be executed N times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a simple join between the two tables:

```
select
    upity.wid,
    webit.email,
    count(*) as count
from
    uptime upity
        join website webby
            on upity.wid=webby.webid
where
    upity.time_stamp>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) 
    and upity.status<>200
group by
    upity.wid,
    webit.email
having count=2
```

I wrote a [really in-depth Q&A on joining tables in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables) which will explain in a lot more detail how this all works. In fact, I wrote it for exactly this reason - be able to help out with a quick query, and then be able to link to a detailed explanation of what is going on.

Edit: As per the comments below between Zerkms and myself, if you take this code, do have a look at the execution times. Large tables can lead to very large datasets when joined and it may indeed be possible that running multiple queries could be more efficient.

Comment: So it's a `JOIN` with `GROUP BY`. Why would it be better than 2 trivial queries?

Comment: @zerkms Because it's not just two queries, but a second query that could potentially be run hundreds/thousands of times inside the loop?

Comment: you can use `webid IN (<a list of primary keys>)` and that will be almost instant. Whereas `JOIN` with `GROUP BY` will lead to a terrible execution plan.

Comment: If there are loads of rows matched, how would running an almost instant query be better than joining the tables on the same primary keys and running it as a single query?

Comment: do you realize how `GROUP BY` by 2 keys that are in the different tables will work?

Comment: If you mean the technical data, no. I would assume it writes the collected rows to a temp table and then sorts through them to aggregate?

Comment: yep, something like that. And the `JOIN`ed result set (the one after `JOIN` + `WHERE` but before `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`) could be **MUCH BIGGER** than the result set from the first query.

Comment: Not saying it isn't possible, but I would think it was a rare instance where it would be more efficient to run many quieries. If it was mine and this came up, I would certainly run both to see how it functions and go with the better option. Surely if his code takes 2 seconds to execute now, and a change makes it run for 20, it's obvious that it really isn't more efficient :)

Comment: "I would certainly run both to see" --- indeed. That's why it worth telling to OP that 2 queries don't generally worse than one. The opposite is true as well. I started discussing it here because for me it's obvious OP tries to perform some "optimization" without understanding if it's required or even worth trying.

Comment: now I can go to sleep - another potential OP misleading is avoided :-) +1

Comment: @zerkms Have a good one, and nice to see you keeping me honest. I answer to learn and it's always nice to be reminded that things aren't black and white all the time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$dat=  mysql_query("SELECT wid,count(*) as count 
FROM uptime WHERE time_stamp>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AND  status<>200 GROUP BY wid ORDER BY  time_stamp ASC");
while($ans= mysql_fetch_assoc($dat)){
if($ans['count']==2){
  $id=$value['wid'];
 $add=  mysql_query("SELECT email FROM website WHERE webid='".$id."'");
$result=  mysql_fetch_assoc($add);
<--etc etc to send email-->
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$dat = mysql_query("
SELECT 
    ut.wid,ut.count(*) as count,ws.email 
FROM 
     uptime as ut 
INNER JOIN
     website as ws 
ON  
     ut.id=ws.webid  
WHERE 
     ut.time_stamp>=DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) AND  ut.status<>200 AND ut.count=2 
GROUP BY  
      ut.wid  
ORDER BY  
       ut.time_stamp ASC");
```